# Unable to drop database link "database link of same name has an open connection"

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, dblink, oracle19c

I'm trying to drop a database link and I get this error "database link of same name has an open connection"

```
drop database link "dbl_prod1"
Error report -
ORA-02018: database link of same name has an open connection
02018. 00000 -  "database link of same name has an open connection"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot drop a database link that has an active/open connection to another database. You must explicitly close the connection first. That process is described in this blog post: https://odenysenko.wordpress.com/2017/03/09/explicitly-closing-oracle-database-link/

Use one of the following methods to explicitly close an open link:

> 1. ALTER SESSION CLOSE DATABASE LINK my_db_link;
> 2. EXECUTE DBMS_SESSION.CLOSE_DATABASE_LINK(‘my_db_link‘);
>
> To successfully close [a] database link:
>
> - [The] database link [has] to be opened first, or you will get ORA-02081:
>   database link is not open
> - All distributed transactions [originating] from
>   your session, that use this particular database link, must be COMMITed
>   or ROLLed BACK, or you will get ORA-02080: database link is in use
> - All cursors that [use] remote objects through this particular database
>   link must be closed first, or you will get ORA-02080: database link is
>   in use
>
> To check if [a] DB link is currently used (has open transactions
> and/or open cursors) [the] next SQL statement may be used:

```
     select db_link, logged_on, open_cursors, in_transaction 
       from v$dblink
      where db_link like 'my_db_link';
```

> References:
>
> [1034343.6 How To Close Remote Connections](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/main/article?cmd=show&type=NOT&id=1034343.6)

Once the link is closed you should be able to drop it.