# Error is -database link of same name has an open connection Error

Tags: python, database, oracle, oracle11g, dblink

```
del_db='drop database link my_db_link' 
cur.execute(del_db)
```

This is a simple query to drop the link database which is executed in SQL developer but it getting error in python -

```
database link of same name has an open connection.
```

Can anyone please help

Comment: as for me error explain all - database is used by some other program and this block it. You would have to find out what other program use database and stop it.

Comment: This statement is coded at last in the module when the whole processing is completed so how can find where the database is blocked. Pl help me out

Comment: maybe you didn't close some connection in code and it Python still keep it open. OR maybe you should close `SQL developer` because it can keep it open.

Comment: not like that . I am selecting the records only from this link database. This is only to create a link with the production database. so created a link database and select records after that at the end just dropping it.

Comment: The connection is established when the link is first created. You must wait for it to time out (per the session rules in the remote database) or explicitly close it from the client side. You can't drop it as long as the connection is open.

Comment: @pmdba ..Do you have any sample code

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62506595/unable-to-drop-database-link-database-link-of-same-name-has-an-open-connection/62506764#62506764

Comment: @pmdba..provided link is not helpful for me ..as per document I tried to execute but still stuck there